# Javascript to find a hidden field value in a datagrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid

I have a an asp:DataGrid which has columns and also another asp:DataGrid nested inside it. This shows my data correctly. I have been asked to change things so that the data in the nested datagrid is displayed as links, so that when selected, the associated file content is shown. Shown below is part of the markup. It shows the nested datagrid, a hidden field and the filename shown as a link. I have a javascript function (not shown) called “viewFile” that does the showing of the file which it is expecting to be passed a fileId. When a link is selected my viewField function is called but the fileId is not passed to it. I am assuming that the javascript “javascript:viewFile($('#hdFileId').val()” is not finding the hidden field. Can anyone advise if I am doing this wrong or can they help with providing the correct javascript?

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Files" >
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dgFileList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="False" GridLines="None">
           <Columns>

               <asp:TemplateColumn>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdFileId" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileId") %>'/>

                       <a href="javascript:viewFile($('#hdFileId').val())"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %></a>

                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateColumn>
           </Columns>
       </asp:DataGrid>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

====EDIT=====================

Here is the whole section of markup for the datagrid:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <div style="float: left; width: 100%; padding-top: 20px;">

        <asp:DataGrid AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowCustomPaging="True" Width="90%"
            CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyField="AccountNumber" UseAccessibleHeader="true"
            GridLines="None" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_header" ID="dgFileView" OnItemCommand="dgFileView_OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="dgFileList_ItemDataBound"
            OnPageIndexChanged="MyDataGrid_Page"
            runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
            PageSize="18"
            PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages"
            PagerStyle-PageButtonCount="20"
            PagerStyle-ForeColor="Navy"
            PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="right"
            ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="top">

           <Columns>

              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="SortByCompany">
                 <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_header_cell" />
                 <ItemStyle CssClass="grid_item_no_edit" />
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Company")%>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>

              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Distribution Group" SortExpression="SortByDistributionGroup">
                 <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_header_cell" />
                 <ItemStyle CssClass="grid_item_no_edit" />
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEnrolmentDevice" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DistributionGroup")%>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>

              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Account ID" >
                 <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_header_cell" />
                 <ItemStyle CssClass="grid_item_no_edit" />
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAccountId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("AccountNumber")%>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>



              <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Files" >
                 <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid_header_cell" />
                 <ItemStyle CssClass="grid_item_no_edit" />
                 <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DataGrid ID="dgFileList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="False" GridLines="None">
                         <Columns>


                             <asp:TemplateColumn>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdFileId" Value='kkk'/>


                                     <a href="javascript:viewFile($('#<%= hdFileId.ClientID %>').val())" style="color: blue; text-decoration: none"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %></a>


                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateColumn>
                         </Columns>
                     </asp:DataGrid>
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateColumn>


           </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>             
     </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID of an ASP element is not the same than the ID of the html element created. You can get it with *yourElement.ClientID*

In jQuery, to get your element :

```
$('#<%= hdFileId.ClientID %>').val()
```

or in classic JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById('<%= hdFileId.ClientID %>').value
```

======= EDIT ========

OK I get it. Your HiddenField is into a GridView, so you have (number of rows) hiddenfields. So you can't access to an unique HiddenField.
To access to each HiddenField you have to do it in the RowDataBound method :

```
protected void dgFileList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        (HiddenField) hdFileId = (HiddenField) e.Row.FindControl("hdFileId");

     }
}
```

In your case, you should add a `<asp:LinkButton>` rather than the html link element `<a>`, and then you could access in the code-behind to set the HREF of the LinkButton for each HiddenField.

Another solution is to not use an HiddenField (which is an ASP element) because you must pass by the code-behind. But you can use a `<span>` which you set as `style="display:none"` to be invisible and you can access directly in your javascript code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed my code so the href looks like this:  href="javascript:viewFile($('#<%= hdFileId.ClientID %>').val())"  but I now get an error saying "The name 'hdFileId' does not exist in the current context". Any ideas?

Comment: Does your hdFileId have the Visible="false" attribute ? Because in this case, javascript can't get the element. Else, javascript should get the value of it. Try to just alert($('#<%= hdFileId.ClientID %>').val()) in the $(document).ready just to know if it can get the value of your hiddenfield

Comment: I added the line to the document ready as you asked but the page won't load. It just shows the error "The name 'hdFileId' does not exist in the current context". In the editor I can hover over the "hdFileId" text and visual studio says "Cannot resolve symbol hdFileId".

Comment: The hidden field - hdFileId doesn't have Visible="false" set.

Comment: I have now added the whole markup for the datagrid in my original question.

Comment: Could you access to this hiddenfield in the code behind ? Like (HiddenField) hdFileId = (HiddenField) this.FindControl('hdFileId'); And then get the hdFileId.Value ?

Comment: OK I understood. As your HiddenField is in a GridView, after the pageload there will be (number of rows) hiddenField, so javaScript can't get a unique HiddenField. To access to each hiddenField, the solution is to get it into the OnRowDataBound method. I will edit my first response with the code to do it.

Comment: Many thanks for this. My code now works by adding the code-behind function.